# Linear programming question: Sensitivity Analysis

Tags: linear-programming

I was given a problem where a home computer table sells for  $36$ dollars  and uses $6$ board ft of lumber, $2$ finishing hrs, and $2$ carpentry hrs.
Should the company manufacture any home computer tables?

Given LP:

$\max$  $z$ = $60x_1$ + $30x_2$ + $20$$x_3$

$st.$

$8x_1$ + $6x_2$ + $1$$x_3$  $\leq 48$ (Lumber)

$4x_1$ + $2x_2$ + $1.5$$x_3$  $\leq 20$ (Finishing)

$2x_1$ + $1.5x_2$ + $0.5$$x_3$  $\leq 8$ (Carpentry)

$x_1$ , $x_2$, $x_3$  $  \geq 0$

---

The only solution the textbook gave was that it is not possible to build home computer table. 
However, I didn't understand why it is. I did the tableau to show some of my findings of the final result

---

[Problem given from textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mI4j.jpg)

---

\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr|r|r}
           row & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & BV         \\ \hline
           0   & 1 & -60 & -30 & -20 &   0 &   0 &  0  & z= 0        \\ \hline
           1   & 0 &   8 &   6 &   1 &   1 &   0 &  0  & s_1 = 48     \\
           2   & 0 &   4 &   2 & 1.5 &   0 &   1 &  0  & s_2 = 20      \\ 
           3   & 0 &   2 & 1.5 & 0.5 &   0 &   0 &  1  & s_3 = 8
\end{array}

\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr|r|r}
           row & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & BV         \\ \hline
           0   & 1 &   0 &  15 & -5 &   0 &   0 &  30  & z= 240        \\ \hline
           1   & 0 &   0 &   0 &   -1 &   1 &   0 &  -4  & s_1 = 16     \\
           2   & 0 &   0 &  -1 & 0.5 &   0 &   1 &  2  & s_2 = 4      \\ 
           3   & 0 &   1 &-0.75 & 0.25 &   0 &   0 &  1/2  & s_3 = 4
\end{array}

\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr|r|r}
           row & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & BV         \\ \hline
           0   & 1 &   0 &   5 & 0 &   0 &   10 &  10  & z= 280        \\ \hline
           1   & 0 &   0 &   -2 &   0 &   1 &   2 &  -8  & s_1 = 16     \\
           2   & 0 &   0 &  -2  & 1 &   0 &   2 &  -4  & s_2 = 4      \\ 
           3   & 0 &   1 & 1.25 & 0 &   0 &   -0.5 &  1.5  & s_3 = 4
\end{array}

$x_1$ $= 2$ , $x_3$ $= 8$ $and$  $Max$ $ z$ $= 280$

Comment: It is hard to understand what the exercise is about. I would recommend to post the whole exercise, maybe word by word.

Comment: pdf: https://itslearningakarmazyan.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/operation-research-aplications-and-algorithms.pdf   on page 288

Comment: I suggest you show us your optimal tableau.  Here's a [MathJax guide for simplex tableaux](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27756/290189).  You may try thinking of the dual.  This is like adding a constraint in the dual.

Comment: where is the "Sensitivity Analysis" part ?